# batch annotation for similar pdf files

Tags: pdf, pdftk, annotate

I have many pdf files with same layout in which I need to fill in some details with plain text and sign in certain places with company stamp.
I am trying to automate things, so I am after a way to fill in the details + stamp the first file and then "copy-paste" that operation to all files.

I managed to find:

1. online websites allowing me to annotate one file at a time
2. documentation on how to use pdftk and additional tools to create a script, but it can take a lot of manual operations via command line (e.g. scaling the signature jpeg file, positioning it, adding text in right location etc.)  which is very tedious.

Is there any way to annotate the first file using visual tools (like #1) and then extract a script of commands to perform these annotations from command line ?
I can then use that script on multiple files.

Thank you,
-Moshe

Comment: understood. but as I described in the question, I would like to automate the process. It is quite tedious and time consuming to prepare the stamp file using manual commands. I would like to annotate the first file using modern tools/websites by editing it visually and then extract a script of commands describing all the annotations I made.

Comment: I checked [this page](https://gist.github.com/chrpinedo/a2a2af757e96aec0d6f69d707629a01a) for example. It is time consuming to position the stamps and texts from command line. I would like to do the first file visually and then get a macro to repeat the same on other files

Comment: Indeed I am looking for a "macro recorder" where I record visual actions of adding texts/images to pdf and the output of the recorder is a script that I can run from command line to repeat these actions on other files.

Comment: K J - not sure I understand your comment.
Suppose I have to insert a text box + add a signature, then why wouldn't these 2 annotations translate to 2 pdftk commands? (maybe 2-5 which is fine)

Anyway - the original question stand in place and I would appreciate if someone finds a solution

Comment: I didn't realize this is going to be a difficult one... would appreciate help